# Textfield inside a scroll view only moves up after keyboard appears IOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, keyboard, uitextfield

I have the following problem: I have a `scrollView` that has a `textField` inside it. I need that when i tap on the `textField` the keyboard shows up and `textField` (inside the scroll) moves up immediately (at the same time) keyboard shows. Right now `textField` appears but with a delay, like a few milliseconds after keyboard shows, like this:

[image: click here to see the problem]

UPDATE:

I have override the methods for keyboard handling like this:

```
override func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification!) {
    guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo, let frame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue else {
        return
    }

    // this constraint -> viewContainerButtonBottomConstraint 
    //refers to the button that must have above the keyboard 
    //when keyboard shows up.   
    self.viewContainerButtonBottomConstraint.constant = frame.height
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)

    let contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: frame.height, right: 0)
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInset

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        self.viewContainerButtonBottomConstraint.constant -= self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
    }
}

override func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification!) {
    scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero

    self.viewContainerButtonBottomConstraint.constant = 0

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

The Registration of observers are made in a parent class:

```
- (void)addNotificationKeyboard {
    if (kKeyboardNotificationsShowAvailable) {
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self

     selector:@selector(keyboardWillShowNotification:)

     name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:nil];
   }
   if (kKeyboardNotificationsHideAvailable) {
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self

     selector:@selector(keyboardWillHideNotification:)

     name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];
}
```

}

And methods keyboardWillShowNotification and keyboardWillHideNotification are also in parent class, they are override like I showed above:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShowNotification:(NSNotification*)notification
{
   NSDictionary* keyboardInfo = [notification userInfo];
   NSValue* keyboardFrameBegin = [keyboardInfo 
   valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
   self.keyboardHeight = [keyboardFrameBegin CGRectValue].size.height;
}

- (void)keyboardWillHideNotification:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    if (self.view.frame.origin.y != 0) {
    if (self.tabBarController) {
        if (!(self.view.frame.origin.y == 64))
            [UIUtilities moveView:self.view newYposition:-64];
    }
    else
        [UIUtilities moveView:self.view newYposition:0];
    }
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Thanks in advance for the answer!

Comment: Add images inline rather than as links.

Comment: That seems to be the default behavior in most Apple apps, it seems like it's done on purpose. You could calculate the required offset and set it to the `contentInset.bottom` property of your scroll or table view, but I would strongly advice leaving the OS implementation in place.

Comment: I think you might be using `keyBoardDidShow` instead of `keyboardWillShow` notification.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri i'm using keyboardWillShow.. :(, although i tried override both methods and still the same

Comment: Show your notification registration code and the selector methods please.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri done

Comment: I don’t think you understood me. I need the code inside the view controller where you register these selector methods.

Comment: Why is the constant being changed after animate block in ‘keyboardWillShow’. The order of the code matters. If you wanted that to happen in the same set of statements, it won’t. That constant will only be updated next time 'layoutIfNeeded()' is called.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri i have updated my answer

Comment: What is the purpose of this line ?
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        self.viewContainerButtonBottomConstraint.constant -= self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
    }

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not hard to do. There is a system notification called `UIKeyboardWillShow` that is sent before a keyboard is displayed. Watch for that. It's user info contains all the information about the size and position that the keyboard will be when it's on screen, and the animation that will be used to get it there. All you have to do then is immediately fire off a matching animation to move or adjust your display. Both animations will then run at the same time.

Comment: i have updated my question to show the override methos for keyboard handling, I didn't understand what matching animation are you refering to .

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have:

```
@objc func adjustForKeyboard(notification: Notification)
{
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardScreenEndFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    let keyboardViewEndFrame = view.convert(keyboardScreenEndFrame, from: view.window)

    if notification.name == Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide
    {
        self.scrollForm.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    }
    else
    {
        self.scrollForm.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardViewEndFrame.height, right: 0)
    }
    self.scrollForm.scrollIndicatorInsets = self.scrollForm.contentInset
    //let selectedRange = self.scrollForm.selectedRange
    //self.scrollForm.scrollRangeToVisible(selectedRange)
}
```

And within the `viewDidLoad()`:

```
    let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)
```

This is probably similar to what you have, try replace your overrides with the above.

Comment: The tag says 'Swift', but it seems you're using a lot of Objective-C.